# How to convert Java Iterator equivalent in c#?

Tags: java, c#, iterator, ienumerable, equivalent

I have downloaded 1 project in java in which i need to convert some part of java code in to my c# code.

This is my code in java:

```
public Map<String, String> queryOptions = new HashMap<String, String>();

Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> i = queryOptions.entrySet().iterator();

while (i.hasNext()) {
  Map.Entry<String, String> entry = i.next();

  if (isArray(entry.getValue())) {
    value
      .append(entry.getKey())
      .append(":")
      .append(entry.getValue());
  } 
  else {
    value
     .append(entry.getKey())
     .append(":")
     .append("'")
     .append(entry.getValue())
     .append("'");
  }

  if (i.hasNext()) {
    value.append(",");
  }
}
```

Now I need to convert this code in to my java code.I know **IEnumerable** for **Iterator** is used but i dont know how and in above code java **isArray** function is used too so.is there any same function available in c# too?

```
Dictionary<string,string> queryOptions = new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

How to convert the rest??

Comment: to clarify things: you want to convert from java to c#?

Comment: Yes i want to convert from java to c#

Comment: Downvoter please give me the reason for downvoting?

Comment: i haven't downvoted, but there are several reasons why i should: the question is in horrible english and **really** hard to understand, there are plenty of other questions and examples regarding this topic, it's quite broad and last but not least: SO is not a coding-service, present what you've got and where the problem lies exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
  public Dictionary<String, String> queryOptions = new Dictionary<String, String>();

  ...

  Boolean isFirst = true;

  // providing that "value" is StringBuilder
  foreach(var pair in queryOptions) {
    if (isFirst) 
      isFirst = false;
    else
      value.Append(',');

    //TODO: what is "isArray" in the context of String?
    if (isArray(pair.Value)) { 
      //TODO: implementing format output will be better
      value.Append(pair.Key);
      value.Append(':');
      value.Append(pair.Value);
    }
    else {
      //TODO: implementing format output will be better
      value.Append(pair.Key);
      value.Append(':');
      value.Append('\'');
      value.Append(pair.Value);
      value.Append('\'');
    }
  }
```

as you can see, you, actually, don't need `Enumerator` (C# equivalent of `Iterartor`) in the context.

Even better approach is to use **Linq**, like this:

```
// "report" is a final string that is exected 
// after value.ToString(); execution
String report = String.Combine(",", queryOptions
  .Select(pair => String.Format("{0}:{1}", 
     pair.Key, 
     isArray(pair.Value) ? pair.Value : "'" + pair.Value + "'"))
  );
```

but you've provided *too few detailes* to write it for sure.